# How can I write that SQL statement analyzing the frequency of used keywords?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql database containing blog articles. Each article has multiple keywords that are m:n linked by using table 'art_key'.

Table containing the article itself:

```
table articles {
  id, 
  title,
  text
}
```

Table containing each keyword once:

```
table keywords {
  id,
  word
}
```

Table linking the articles and keywords together: One article contain multiple keywords and one keyword can be used in multiple articles.

```
table art_key {
  id,
  article_id,
  keyword_id
}
```

Some of the articles contain pictures. Those have an additional keyword "[PICTURE]".

For analysis I'd like to see how often (in how many articles) each keyword has been used and for each keyword: what percentage of the articles containing this keywords have a picture (have keyword "[PICTURE]").

Additionally, the analysis should be case-insensitive and leading blanks removed. So the keywords 'sql', ' SQL', 'sqL ', 'SqL' should be seen as one keyword 'sql'.

How can I write that query using an SQL statement?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show use your first attemps or are you looking for some free work?

Comment: I tried it myself for quite some time, but I'm not so into SQL. Could only make up a solution using a slow python script. Will remember it for the next time, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do what you want. It joins the keyword list to the `art_key` table to find all articles with a given keyword, then joins that to a list of articles which have pictures (which is found by a separate `JOIN` subquery) to determine how many articles with a given keyword have pictures in them. Keywords are pre-processed and grouped for display using [`LOWER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) and [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) to make the result case-insensitive and tolerant of white space.

```
SELECT LOWER(TRIM(k.word)) AS keyword
     , COUNT(DISTINCT a.article_id) AS num_articles
     , COUNT(DISTINCT p.article_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT a.article_id) * 100 AS percent_with_pictures
FROM keywords k
LEFT JOIN art_key a ON a.keyword_id = k.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.article_id
                , COUNT(DISTINCT a.article_id) AS num_pictures
           FROM art_key a
           JOIN keywords k ON k.id = a.keyword_id AND LOWER(TRIM(k.word)) = '[picture]'
           GROUP BY a.article_id) p ON p.article_id = a.article_id
GROUP BY keyword
HAVING COUNT(a.article_id) > 0
```

I created a small [demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a74ca6/2) to show how I've interpreted your question and how the query works.

```
create table keywords (id int auto_increment primary key, word varchar(20));
insert into keywords (word) values
('sql'), ('SQL '), (' SQL'), ('SQl'), (' sQl '), ('MySQL'), ('[PICTURE]');
create table art_key(id int auto_increment primary key, article_id int, keyword_id int);
insert into art_key (article_id, keyword_id) values
(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (2, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4), (4, 5), (4, 2), (4, 6), (1, 7), (4, 7);
```

Output:

```
keyword     num_articles    percent_with_pictures
mysql       2               100
sql         4               50
[picture]   2               100
```

Comment: Thank you!! Just one more thing: 
I’m getting 86 warnings: „division by 0“. Where can these warnings come from? 
Just double-checked all foreign key constraints, they should be okay.

Comment: When I add `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.article_id) > 1` at the end of the statement, the warnings are gone.

Comment: @meini Sorry in my small example I didn't consider the possibility of a keyword that wasn't in any articles. You should be able to fix the query by adding `HAVING COUNT(a.article_id) > 0`; see my edit and updated demo link.

Comment: Of course `>0` not `>1`. You really helped me a lot. Thanks again. :)